# Problem with fopen()

Tags: c

So I am writing a little utility to format my inventory file is such a manner that I can import it to a preexisting db. I am having a large issue trying to just do fscanf. I have read tons of file in c in the past. What am I doing wrong here.

Edit based on Christopher's suggestion still getting NULL.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main ()
{

FILE* stream;
FILE* output;
char sellercode[200];
char asin[15];
string sku[15];
string fnsku[15];
int quality;

stream = fopen("c:\out\dataextract.txt", "r");
output = fopen("c:\out\output.txt", "w");

if (stream == NULL)
{
    return 0;
}

for(;;)
{
    //if (EOF) break;
    fscanf(stream, "%s", sku);
    fprintf(output, "%s %s  %s  %s  %i\n", sku, fnsku, asin, quality);
}
 return 0;
 }
```

Comment: `typedef char* string;` indicates a serious and dangerous misunderstanding of C.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's actually a lot of problems here.  Christopher and mah (in the comment) mentions some of them.  But a bigger problem is that you're not allocating any space to read (and write) your data.

By having `string sellercode = "";` (p.s., do ***not*** define a "string" type, you're only hurting yourself here), you're pointing to a readonly array of char.  You need to actually leave some memory here to read your data in to otherwise you're risking corrupting your memory.

These variables should be declared:

```
char sellercode[SOME_REASONABLE_SIZE];
char asin[SOME_REASONABLE_SIZE];
char sku[SOME_REASONABLE_SIZE];
char fnsku[SOME_REASONABLE_SIZE];
```

with some value of `SOME_REASONABLE_SIZE`.

---

You should also *always* close your files explicitly.  Never leave them open.

---

Last thing I noticed now that you mention it is that you use backslashes in your paths but they are unescaped.  You'll have to escape them.

```
stream = fopen("c:\\out\\dataextract.txt", "r");
output = fopen("c:\\out\\output.txt", "w");
```

Comment: While that is value information, I am still at a lost for why it would come out null.

Comment: @Joe: What is null?  `stream`?  Probably the file doesn't exist or you don't have the permissions to open it.  If you want to know for sure, examine `errno` or use `perror()` to print a descriptive message.  I do notice that you have unescaped backslashes in your paths.

Comment: It is telling me no such file or directory. This is odd since I copied the file location.

Comment: I have escaped them and still the same message. I know my paths are correct and the file does exist. Also output is not being created.

Answer (score 5):

```
if (stream = NULL)
{
    return 0;
}
```

should be

```
if (stream == NULL)
{
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Additionally, you seem to be using fscanf() and fprintf() both on the same stream; you probably mean to use output on your fprintf().

Comment: Thank you, well now I know my file is coming up NULL.

Answer (score 0):

Backslash is escape character inside strings. Use forward slash in your pathnames.
"c:/foo/bar.txt"